# .htaccess not fallowing the requested url | codeigniter url routing

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

The original URL :

https://www.doctor24.ro/i/index.php/en/property/54a402a9d4f13/Sapientek-Ecografie

The requested url after .htaccess :

https://www.doctor24.ro/i/cabinet/Sapientek-Ecografie

The .htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^cabinet/(.*)$ ./index.php/en/property/([a-zA-Z0-9-=_?]+)*$
```

What is the problem ?

**UPDATE :**

The script I'm using uses the **codeigniter url routing** .

Comment: Where does the "54a402a9d4f13" come from?

Comment: What I mean is, how does the property id get into the .htaccess RewriteRule?

Answer (score 0):

**Updated** Try the below now:

```
RewriteRule ^i/cabinet/(.*)$ i/index.php/en/property/$1
```

Comment: Not Found

The requested URL /i/cabinet/Simple-Apartment was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Comment: Is the above .htaccess code snippet your whole .htaccess? are there other rules?

Comment: Also I am noticing that you have this url https://www.doctor24.ro/i/index.php/en/property/54a402a9d4f13/Sapientek-Ecografie and this url https://www.doctor24.ro/i/index.php/en/property/54a402a9d4f13 are both giving the same page, so do you have other sort of redirecting rules on this page?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use regex on right hand side, just use back-reference variable. Also looks like you're placing this .htaccess in `/i/` folder. You will need to use appropriate `RewriteBase` as well:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /i/

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^cabinet/(.*)$ index.php/en/property/$1 [L,NC]
```